# PHP get variable's name of class instance?

Tags: php, class, instance

I'm new to PHP so this question seems stupid, but suppose I'm assigning variable ABC with value to be a new object of class XYZ, then how could I get the name "ABC" inside XYZ's class definition ?

```
$ABC = new XYZ;
$ABC->echoInstanceName(); //--I wish this line could echo out : ABC
```

Is this easier when the instance is assigned to an array's element ?

```
$ABC = array('myElem'=>new XYZ);
$ABC['myElem']->echoInstanceName(); //--I wish this line could echo out : ABC
```

All suggestions appreciated !

---

**More infos** : I'm doing kind of thing: build a system of animals.

Started with class nativeAnimal & extended to Monkey, Elephant, Fish...etc. And in runtime, I create a 2-tiers array that each array's element is an instance of type Monkey, Elephant, or Fish...

I want the **array's key is the animal's name**. And inside the class Monkey, I want a function to echo the Monkey's name. Of course I can pass the array's key to the instance somehow, but I want to avoid typing it twice. (That can lead to error(s) later when I change just one name)

Is this so impossible ? Or could you please suggest a better pattern ? Thanks !

Comment: It's not generally possible to do so. Why do you (think you) need this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this. If you want to pass `ABC` value to the `XYZ` class, do it with an extra argument in constructor:

```
$ABC = new XYZ('ABC');
```

There is no other way to inform class about variable that it was assigned to.

Example `XYZ` class:

```
class XYZ {
  protected $name;
  public __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public echoInstanceName() {
    echo $name;
  }

  public getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could do some `debug_backtrace`ing and introspection and hacking... But there's really no reason to do so, so +1. :)

Comment: I've just added some infos, please see if you could suggest something else. Thanks !

Comment: In my opinion you can pass animal's name to the constructor and skip the array keys. Then you can work with foreach and just call method `getName()` on the animals objects.